# How to setup the debugger in qtcreator2.3

Tags: qt-creator

I'm facing a problem when I setup the debugger(with python support) in qtcreator. I create a clone of gcc in tool-chain and in debugger path I've put the debugger which come with qtcreator(from the folder pythongdb/). But when I start the debugger, it says :

```
dQUEUE: RUN ENGINE
dCALL: RUN ENGINE
<91-exec-run
>91^error,msg="Don't know how to run.  Try \"help target\"."
dDon't know how to run.  Try "help target".
dNOTE: ENGINE RUN FAILED
```

Can anyone help please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Decent first question, but avoid signing your posts. Your profile is linked to all your questions.

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917377/gdb-claims-it-doesnt-know-how-to-run. Look there, it seems like an issue with 64-bit architecture.